# SwiftUI chessBoard view with random field colors - unable to compile

Tags: swiftui, compiler-optimization, chess

I have a super simple chessboard structure in SwiftUI and wanted to give each field a random color, but Xcode cannot compile it.

I can provide a single color, or 2 colors with the following function:
`let color = (row + column) % 2 == 0 ? Color.green : Color.blue` and using `fill(color)` but random like shown below does not work giving me the warning that it could not compile in time.

I also tried to check the ID and provide a color from another array, but even this does not work.

Is my structure completely off?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var lastTappedSquareID: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChessBoard(squareSize: 50, lastTappedSquareID: $lastTappedSquareID)
            if let squareID = lastTappedSquareID {
                Text("Last Tapped Square ID: \(squareID)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChessBoard: View {
    let rows    : Int = 8
    let columns : Int = 8
    let squareSize: CGFloat
    @Binding var lastTappedSquareID: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<columns) { column in
                        let id = Int(row * columns + column + 1)
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill([Color.green, Color.blue, Color.brown, Color.darkGray].randomElement()!)
                                .frame(width: squareSize, height: squareSize)
                                .id(id)
                                .border(id == lastTappedSquareID ? .red : .clear, width: 3)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    lastTappedSquareID = id
                                }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's having trouble with your `fill` line. I've split it into a separate function. Note also that `darkGray` isn't available on `Color` -- I've changed it to `orange`

```
func randomRectangleColor() -> Color {
        [Color.green, Color.blue, Color.brown, Color.orange].randomElement()!
    }
```

```
.fill(randomRectangleColor())
```

A basic/general strategy for the error you encountered is to comment out sections of the code until you find the culprit -- that's what I did to identify the problem line (your code compiles without the `fill` line)

Comment: ok thanks, that means I should handle all logics out of the views and do only very basic calculations in there?

Comment: Not necessarily. But, it’s a bit hard to predict.